# what the difference between IS OF and TREAT() in oracle11g

Tags: oracle11g

i'm confused about IS OF and TREAT(). what the difference between IS OF and TREAT() (when come to sub-type and super-type) in oracle?

Answer (score 2):

*IS OF* is an operator that tests an object and returns either *true* or *false*.

*TREAT* is a function that converts an object and returns an object.

So use *IS OF* it you just want to test whether an object is of some more specific subtype. Use *TREAT* if you not only want to test but use the object.